# ESP8226 connected by USB to TTL using USB A to USB Mini B cable to temperature sensor DHT22 error with Arduino IDE - upload (Thingsboard IOT WIFI)

Tags: wifi, iot, esp8266, arduino-ide, thingsboard

While uploading the compiled code of Arduino IDE shows the following error in Arduino IDE console while connected ESP8266 Wifi module to DHT22 - Temperature and humidity sensor through USB to TTL for IOT application using things board as shown in the schematic diagram.

Warnings and errors when uploading:

> warning: espcomm_sync failed
>
> error: espcomm_open failed
>
> error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
>
> error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

How to fix this error?

Hardware wiring schematics:

[image]

Code used for compiling (File Name: esp8266-dht-mqtt.ino) and upload in Arduino IDE:

```
#include <dummy.h>

#include "DHT.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ThingsBoard.h>

#define WIFI_AP "aerpace_wifi"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "********"

#define TOKEN "eQ69bCealkcqbybc****"

// DHT
#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

char thingsboardServer[] = "3.1**.**9.***";

WiFiClient wifiClient;

// Initialize DHT sensor.
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

ThingsBoard tb(wifiClient);

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
unsigned long lastSend;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  dht.begin();
  delay(10);
  InitWiFi();
  lastSend = 0;
}

void loop() {
  if (!tb.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }

  if (millis() - lastSend > 1000) {  // Update and send only after 1 seconds
    getAndSendTemperatureAndHumidityData();
    lastSend = millis();
  }

  tb.loop();
}

void getAndSendTemperatureAndHumidityData() {
  Serial.println("Collecting temperature data.");

  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  float humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();

  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(humidity) || isnan(temperature)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("Sending data to ThingsBoard:");
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(humidity);
  Serial.print(" %\t");
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temperature);
  Serial.println(" *C ");

  tb.sendTelemetryFloat("temperature", temperature);
  tb.sendTelemetryFloat("humidity", humidity);
}

void InitWiFi() {
  Serial.println("Connecting to AP ...");
  // attempt to connect to WiFi network

  WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to AP");
}


void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!tb.connected()) {
    status = WiFi.status();
    if (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
      WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
      Serial.println("Connected to AP");
    }
    Serial.print("Connecting to ThingsBoard node ...");
    if (tb.connect(thingsboardServer, TOKEN)) {
      Serial.println("[DONE]");
    } else {
      Serial.print("[FAILED]");
      Serial.println(" : retrying in 5 seconds]");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```